# long SQL LIKE statement with bracket

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I want to validate the phrase below. It has commas and brackets. I have multiple combinations, but it doesn't seem to work.

> `Request to do abc is completed ([GU7: Currently True:Yes/Always true:Yes], [SPM1: Currently True:Yes/Always true:Yes])`

Please help me validate this using `LIKE`.

I have tried --

- `LIKE Request to do abc is completed%` ---> This works but I want to validate complete Phrase
- `LIKE %GU7: Currently True:Yes/Always true:Yes%`   ---> Does not work

The column form which I'm trying to retrieve is varchar datatype.

I wan to retrieve anything from this column which has "GU7: Currently True:Yes/Always true:Yes" present in the above description.

Comment: You might need to expland a little about your table structure and it would be helpfull to have your SQL statement here as well.

Comment: [Works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f522c/2/0).

Comment: I think what you have there is the CrLf (\r\n, \r, or \n) somewhere in the string. Whatever SQL query viewer you have omits the special characters and displays it as a single line string. You need to adjust you query viewer to display all characters

Comment: Try the [ESCAPE expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) and escape the square brakets. `WHERE string LIKE 'Request to update abc  is completed (\[6EM1: currently true:Yes/always true group:Yes\], \[SPM1: currently true:Yes/always true group:No\])' ESCAPE '\'`